# Results for multiple table differences in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query to compare 2 tables using a left outer join and gives me the records in table tb1 which are not there in tb101

```
select id
from tb1 a1
   left outer join tb101 a2 on a1.id = a2.id
where a2.id is null
  and a1.time > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

I want to get results for comparing tables tb2 to tb202, tb3 to tb303,.. all in the same query. No changes are required in the query, except the table names

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this comparing anything?

Comment: *I want to get results for comparing multiple tables (t2,t3,..) in the 2 DBs (db1,db2) in the same query.* Multiple tables - multiple queries. Or stored procedure with dynamic SQL.

Comment: It gives me the id of records from db1.tb1 which are not present in bd2.tb1 within the time frame

Comment: Do you realise that you change your question so much that is another question now right ?

Comment: yeah, my bad. But I thought this would be better understood.

Comment: So, If I need everything in same query, Stored Proc is my only choice?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure to understand you're question but I think you forget to put the schema.
[Database].[schema].[table]
exemple : db2.dbo.tb1

But you can also use a "not in" or "Not Exists" filter if you execute it on db1 database:

```
select id
from tb1
where id not in (SELECT id from db2.dbo.tb1)
```

Comment: Do you possibily realise that maybe is your question that is not clear ?? 

Just try to help, but yes, resolve it

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. Your solution is **NOT** applicable for OP. `db2.dbo.tb1` will fail.

Comment: PS. *you can also use a "not in" or "Not Exists"* They are **NOT** equivalent until `id` in both tables is NOT NULL.